# RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'spine': Input to rig type must be a chain of 3 or more bones. Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, error, rigify

I am trying to generate a rig for this dog mesh using Blenders rigify cat rig (I heard there are some bugs with Rigify's dog rig) however I ran across this error  ***"RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'spine': Input to rig type must be a chain of 3 or more bones. Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'"*** when clicking the generate rig button in Object Data Properties.

Alongside the error message an extra bone appears, labeled ORG-pelvis.C
I thought one of my bones might not be attached correctly so I checked "*connected*" in every bones properties but still had no luck. I also tried to snap all the children bones to their parents by using snap cursor to selection on the parent bone and then, snap selection to cursor on the child bone but I still encounter this error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJw7y.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a blend file with the metarig.  You don't need to include the dog.  It'll be easier to figure out why RIGIFY thinks your spine is messed up.  Meanwhile, what metarig did you start from, and have you edited anything beyond removing the face?

Comment: @MartyFouts I am actually new on Stack exchange so I am not sure how to upload a .Blend file on here, but I added a cat Meta Rig. Besides removing the face I also deleted all the toe bones for the paws except f_toe_R/L and r_toe.R/L.

Comment: [How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)  Deleting those bones should not have caused your problem, so seeing your blend file would be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the link on how to exchange .blend files , by disabling "connected" alongside deleting the problematic bones, then re-adding the bones with their labels and parent child relationships, I was able to fix the errors. Unfortunately, the generated rig ended up having missing parts and being incomplete. I have uploaded a file to it here if you want to check it out. Thanks! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=gPmkQe7y" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/gPmkQe7y/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you disconnected the spine chain somewhere... or maybe you connected a bone that shouldn't be connected.

The rule for the individual Rigify parts is:
All bones of one "rig type" must be parented **and** connected. Individual rig types can be parented **but not** connected.

I hope this makes sense. From what you describe, enabling "connected" parenting for all bones is definitely a mistake.

If you share the actual file, identifying the actual problem should be easy.

Comment: Thank you for the help. disabling "connected" alongside deleting the problematic bones, then re-adding the bones with their labels and parent child relationships, fixed the errors. Unfortunately, the generated rig ended up having missing parts and being incomplete. I have uploaded a file to it here if you want to check it out. Thanks! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=gPmkQe7y" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/gPmkQe7y/)

Comment: Nice! Yes, most of your Rig Types are missing and that's why the rig doesn't generate in full. I am not sure why, there are a few ways in which Rig Types may be lost. Or maybe you never assigned them. Do you know how to set rig types?
(Startiung from scratch may be a good idea, by the way :D )

Comment: Thank you so much :). That's odd that some of the rig types are missing. Maybe I accidently deleted them when I reorganized my collection. Welp starting from scratch it is :)

Comment: It could be because of this common Blender issue tho. Understanding it may help you avoid losing work.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcGM14fa6E0

Comment: Great video, I think this bug might be the case. I did use  control-z  a lot while working in rigify this time around. I also gave you a subscribe ;) (I'm listed as Lilylikesslugs on youtube). Thanks again for the help.